# How to count the number of isset()s?

Tags: php, arrays

I used:

```
 $multi = array();
 // multi is filled with integers $i and $k $multi[$i][$k]
 // …
 if( count($multi[$i][$k]) + count($multi[$i+1][$k]) + count($multi[$i+1][$k+1]) == 2 ) {}
```

gives me in PHP 7.2 the error:

> Error : count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Now I considered changing the `if` to:

```
 if( !empty($multi[$i][$k]) && !empty($multi[$i+1][$k]) && !empty($multi[$i+1][$k+1])) {}
```

But the $multi slots can have `0` as values, plus it does not count if 2 slots are set.

Alternative:

```
 if( isset($multi[$i][$k]) && isset($multi[$i+1][$k]) && isset($multi[$i+1][$k+1])) {}
```

However, my goal is to count that exactly **two values** are set. Now I am wondering how I can count the `isset()`s.

Maybe it's too early, because I cannot see the solution.

Comment: did you check with `empty()`

Comment: show us some dummy data for `$multi`

Comment: I added this info: $multi is filled with integers $i and $k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count `issets`, do it. PHP casts boolean to int while summing

```
$a = 0;
$b = "";
echo isset($a) + isset($b) + isset($c); // 2
```

Comment: So simple and great. Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't know you can count them like that!

Answer (score 0):

because of `true` can mean `1` then you can use `+` operator with `isset` to make it work

```
$condition = isset($multi[$i][$k]) + isset($multi[$i+1][$k]) + isset($multi[$i+1][$k+1]);
if($condition == 2) {
   echo 'passes'
}
```